# Exchanging the limit and integral can be restricted to smaller measurable sets

Tags: real-analysis

**Problem Statement:**

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of nonnegative measurable functions converging pointwise to some measurable function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$ and suppose that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}}f_n dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}}fdx < \infty.$$

Show that for each measurable set $A,$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_A f_n dx = \int_A fdx < \infty.$$

**My comments:**

This problem is from an old real analysis qualifying exam. The book we are using is Real Analysis by Royden and Fitzpatrick (4th edition).

I'm thinking that maybe we need to use Fatou's Lemma...

I'd be happy with just a hint, Thanks!

Comment: Weird question.   I don't know what the multiplication of integrals is supposed to be doing, seems to be a useless distraction.   Anyway since $f_n, f$ are nonnegative, then the integral over a smaller domain cannot be larger than the integral over a larger domain.

Comment: I forgot to write equals signs between the integrals. Oops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generalized Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem:
\begin{align*}
\int_{A}f_{n}(x)dx&=\int_{{\bf{R}}}f_{n}(x)\chi_{A}(x)dx\\
\int_{A}f(x)dx&=\int_{{\bf{R}}}f(x)\chi_{A}(x)dx,
\end{align*}
and we see that $f_{n}(x)\chi_{A}(x)\leq f_{n}(x)$, $f_{n}(x)\chi_{A}(x)\rightarrow f(x)\chi_{A}(x)$ pointwise and $f_{n}(x)\rightarrow f(x)$ pointwise, and $\displaystyle\int_{{\bf{R}}}f_{n}(x)dx\rightarrow\int_{{\bf{R}}}f(x)dx$, so the result follows.

Comment: No reason for $\int f_n \rightarrow \int f$.  Consider $f_n(x) = (1/n)1_{x \in [0, n]}$.  So $f_n\rightarrow 0$ but $\int f_n = 1$ for all $n$. The trouble is that there is no bounding function.

Comment: That is one of the assumptions in question.

Comment: What is an assumption in the question?

Comment: That $\displaystyle\int_{{\bf{R}}}f_{n}(x)dx\rightarrow\displaystyle\int_{{\bf{R}}}f(x)dx$.

Comment: I see no place where that assumption is stated.

Comment: Apparently OP missed the equality sign.

Comment: That would explain the weird multiplication of integrals from my above comment.  I didn't think about it as being a typo.